How to support multiple DatabaseContexts on different databases using EF Core?
I am building a tenant-based application that has a main database for application related data and also a database for each tenant. How do I accomplish that the tenant database migrations are not applied to the main database, but rather only to the tenant?
My current thought is to always migrate while in runtime and send the migration to a database management service that is then handling the per database migration.
Is there a more elegant and performance saving approach?

Firstly, if you want to use multiple dbcontext inside thet one asp.net core project, you just need to create different dbcontext class and use it.
Like below:
MainDbContext :
public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MainDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Model configurations for main database
    }
}

TenantDbContext
public class TenantDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<TenantOrder> TenantOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Model configurations for tenant database
    }
}


How do I accomplish that the tenant database migrations are not applied to the main database, but rather only to the tenant?

When do the migration, you could set the migration just for specific dbcontext:
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context MainDbContext -OutputDir Migrations\SqlServerMigrations
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context TenantDbContext  -OutputDir Migrations\SqliteMigrations

More details, you could refer to this article.
